# What application to manage a large collection of short home videos?

Tags: video, tagging

I am new to Linux and I am trying to find my way into the new environment, which I like more and more.
But one point that is getting difficult is to manage my large collection of short home videos (around 2000, in different formats, but mostly .mp4).
I don't need sophisticated editing functions, maybe some basic trimming, but I need a tool to tag those videos with my own keywords.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The default file manager for Ubuntu based systems is called Nautilus or "Gnome Files", which does not natively support tagging. However, Kubuntu and KDE based systems use the Dolphin file manager which does support tagging.

While you can install Dolphin inside a regular Ubuntu system it appears it will not do the tagging functionality. There are some workarounds for Ubuntu based systems, but they are relatively complex and not well supported, whereas KDE and Dolphin support tags in an easy to use way out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that may work for you is to run Kodi which is an open source theater application. It's also designed typically with use in KDE systems, but it will run on regular Ubuntu and supports tagging and browsing of video files in an easy to use way specifically designed for media collections.